# In groovy [].sum() returns null when I expect 0

Tags: groovy

In groovy **[].sum()** returns **null** when I expect **0**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-2411 this is expected behaviour as sum() works
for an array of Strings as well. The solution is to use [].sum(0) which will return 0.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want zero with an empty list, you can always use:

```
List foo = []
def bar = foo.sum() ?: 0
assert bar == 0
```

The elvis operator will only evaluate the right hand side if the left hand side is null.

Comment: That's true, and I was doing that previously to get around the problem. However, .sum(0) seems cleaner to me